# Latitude Longitude in wrong format DDDMM.MMMM 2832.3396N

Tags: javascript, c, gps, embedded, latitude-longitude

I have a gps module that gives me latitude in longitude in a weird format.

```
DDDMM.MMMM
```

As written on user manual, Degrees*100 + Minutes.

As far as I know, It is degrees minutes seconds, and seconds is between 0-59, above than this will increment the minute. But this is giving minutes in decimal places. Does this means 1/1000th of a minute?

```
eg. 07717.3644 E
077 --> degrees
17 --> minutes
3644 --> ?
E --> Direction
```

Also how will I convert it to decimal, I am using the formula

```
decimal = degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/3600.
```

Comment: **.3644** are minutes which are equal to **seconds/60**

Comment: Hi, I am facing similar problem, the nema received format is ddmm.mmmm. I need to convert the same to ddmm.mmmmmm. 1. what this format explains ? ddmm.mmmmmm? Please explain. 2. To convert ddmm.mmmm to ddmm.mmmmmm, I did ddmm.(mmmm* 60). Is this correct

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To convert this to the decimal format, we start by keeping the DD portion and simply divide the MM.MMM by 60 to firm the MMM portion of the decimal format.

```
43. (48.225/60), -79.(59.074/60)  

43.(0.80375), -79.(0.98456)  

43.80375, -79.98456
```

In your case

```
eg. 07717.3644 E is the DDDMM.MMMM format

077 --> degrees
17 --> minutes
.3644 --> minutes equals to sec/60


decimal = degrees + minutes/60 

decimal = 77 + (17.3644 / 60)  

decimal = 77.28941
```

[See this Link Would help you](http://atlanticgeocaching.com/index.php/2012-03-05-22-43-59/articles-a-tutorials/11-how-to-convert-latlon-to-decimal-format)

Comment: Thanks for this, I spend lot of time

Comment: solved my problem as well. I knew about longi but wasn't sure about lati.

Comment: @Gangadhar - dead link

Answer (score 5):

Follow the algorithm to convert the same.

```js
var t = "7523.7983" // (DDMM.MMMM)
var g = "03412.9873" //(DDDMM.MMMM)

function lat(t){
  return (Number(t.slice(0,2)) + (Number(t.slice(2,9))/60))
}

function lng(g) {
  return (Number(g.slice(0,3)) + (Number(g.slice(3,10))/60))
}

console.log(lat(t)) 
console.log(lng(g))
```

Comment: Thanks your code worked as expected result. I got a few device from China who provide this data-format.

Answer (score 4):

The value is not a number but a string of degrees and minutes concatenated.  You need to be careful because it is likely that latitude values only have two degree digits (i.e. DDMM.MMMM), so if you use string handling to separate the values, you'd have to account for that. However both long and lat can be handled numerically as follows:

```
double GpsEncodingToDegrees( char* gpsencoding )
{
    double a = strtod( gpsencoding, 0 ) ;
    double d = (int)a / 100 ;
    a -= d * 100 ;
    return d + (a / 60) ;
}
```

You might also pass the hemisphere character E/W or N/S to this function and use it to determine an appropriate +/- sign if required.

Comment: That is a great solution if going from a string dddmm.mmmm to numeric dd.dddd if the because original string can vary in length

Answer (score 2):

1 minute = 60 seconds, so .3644 minutes = .3644 * 60 = 21.86 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Simple implementation in Python:

```
latitude = <ddmm.mmmm>
longitude = <dddmm.mmmmm>

# Ricava i gradi della latitudine e longitudine
lat_degree = int(latitude / 100);
lng_degree = int(longitude / 100);

# Ricava i minuti della latitudine e longitudine
lat_mm_mmmm = latitude % 100
lng_mm_mmmmm = longitude % 100

# Converte il formato di rappresentazione
converted_latitude = lat_degree + (lat_mm_mmmm / 60)
converted_longitude = lng_degree + (lng_mm_mmmmm / 60)

print converted_latitude, converted_longitude
```

Replace latitude and logitude.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem in Java. I was working with IOT Device which sends location in the form of Latitude i.e  (3231.5462N) and longitude i.e (07406.6945E). I converted them using simple formula take the DD portion for latitude and DDD for longitude  as it is and Apply Conversion of Double in my case you can apply what you desire and convert the string to Double and  remove the 0 automatically  if its on start like in my case and then divide the rest of value with 60 and take the sum of Both .

```
public  double[] convertLocationToLatAndLong(String latitude,String longitude){
double lat=(Double.parseDouble(latitude.substring(0, 2)))+(Double.parseDouble(latitude.substring(2, latitude.length()))/60);
double lon=(Double.parseDouble(longitude.substring(0, 3)))+(Double.parseDouble(longitude.substring(3, longitude.length()))/60);

double[] latAndLong= {lat,lon};
return latAndLong;
```

}